# How to apply safe multi-threading in tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a system that is connected with multiple hardware devices(cameras, router, sensors etc.). So I thought about having a separate GUI that pings the IP addresses of these devices almost every second in order to check whenever a device gets disconnected, and I need to ping them all together.

This is the ping script:

```py
def testRouter(self):
        response = os.popen(f"ping {self.router_ip} {self.count} 1").read()
        if "Received = 1" in response:
            self.router_status.configure(image=self.connected)
            self.router_button.configure(command=self.clickedNone)
        else:
            self.router_status.configure(image=self.disconnected)
            self.router_button.configure(command=self.clickedRouter)
        self.root.after(5000, self.testRouter)
```

But the GUI freezes for more than a minute till it displays the content, and many other times it just freezes forever. So I tried to implement a thread for each ping but I came across the fact that tkinter is not a thread-safe library with an error  `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`

Any idea on how to implement this? (without using mtTkinter please)

Comment: It is better to post what you have tried on using thread, so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: You could create one or multiple threads outside of tkinter, whose role is to ping the devices. At each ping, they would update a variable representing the status of the device.
To make sure that this thread doesn't interfere with TKinter thread (i.e. this thread writes data in the variable while the tkinter thread is reading it), you can use Mutexes (See doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to lock the variable in the getters and setters.

Comment: Put the non-GUI code in threads, and have them send information to the GUI thread via a queue. I think there are questions and answers on this site that give examples of how to do that.